# Is there a way to make sure the provided email is working?

Tags: asp.net, email

I want to send a confirmation email when the user register, but first I want to make sure this email is real and working, is there a way to check this ?
I mean lets say I want to registers with this email: blah@blah.com, on server side I want to send the email address to API or any thing that returns that this email is working, then I'll send the confirmation one.
Is it possible to do so ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This exactly what you want:
[End-to-end Email Address Verification for Applications](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5189/End-to-end-Email-Address-Verification-for-Applicat)

This tutorial consists of three parts:

**1) Validations** 
Some Code:

```
public static bool isEmail(string inputEmail)
{
   inputEmail  = NulltoString(inputEmail);
   string strRegex = @"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}" +
         @"\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\" + 
         @".)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$";
   Regex re = new Regex(strRegex);
   if (re.IsMatch(inputEmail))
    return (true);
   else
    return (false);
}
```

**2) Validating via SMTP Network Connection**

```
string[] host = (address.Split('@'));
string hostname = host[1];

IPHostEntry IPhst = Dns.Resolve(hostname);
IPEndPoint endPt = new IPEndPoint(IPhst.AddressList[0], 25);
Socket s= new Socket(endPt.AddressFamily, 
        SocketType.Stream,ProtocolType.Tcp);
s.Connect(endPt);
```

**3) Validating via SMTP Handshakes**

...more info [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5189/End-to-end-Email-Address-Verification-for-Applicat)

Answer (score 1):

First of all , you can do email validation using regular expression. Like this.

```
public const string MatchEmailPattern = 
            @"^(([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\w-]{2,}))@"
     + @"((([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.([0-1]?
                [0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\."
     + @"([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.([0-1]?
                [0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])){1}|"
     + @"([a-zA-Z]+[\w-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$";

  /// <summary>
  /// Checks whether the given Email-Parameter is a valid E-Mail address.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="email">Parameter-string that contains an E-Mail address.</param>
  /// <returns>True, when Parameter-string is not null and 
  /// contains a valid E-Mail address;
  /// otherwise false.</returns>
  public static bool IsEmail(string email)
  {
     if (email != null) return Regex.IsMatch(email, MatchEmailPattern);
     else return false;
  }
```

Second, you can use 3rd party API to validate Email ( i think, you are looking for this). Some helpful link for API --

- http://verify-email.org/using-api.html
- http://www.email-validator.net/email-address-online-verification-api.html
- http://www.email-checker.com/verify-emails-in-real-time-using-our-api/